# Python - Intra similarity

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to code in Python the intra similarity on the Iris data set.
Which is the distance between elements from the same class.
For example on that set:

```
 1  2  3  4  |0
 5  6  7  8  |0 
 1  3  5  6  |1
11 12 13 14  |0 
10  2  4  6  |1

distance1 = (1-5)^2 + (2-6)^2 + (3 - 7)^2 + (4-8)^2
distance1 = sqrt(distance1)
distance2 = (1- 11)^2 + (2-12)^2 + (3 - 13)^2 + (4-14)^2
distance2 = sqrt(distance2)
similarityClass0 = (ditance1 + distance2) / 2
```

And then I will have to do the same for class 1, 2 , 3 and so on.

For now My code is I think functionnal but pretty ugly 
In input I have X and y. When I finish to compute for tab0, I do the same 
for tab1, tab2 etc.

My question is: How can I create a code for n classes? My goal is also to have for each line a measure of intra similarity

```
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np


iris = datasets.load_iris()

iris.data.shape, iris.target.shape

X = iris.data
#0 = Setosa // 1 = Versicolor // 2 = Virginica
y = iris.target

#At first, we retrieve the indexes of each classes
#For example if tab0 has classes on ligne 1,2,6. Tab0 will store 1,2,6
tab0 = list() 
tab1 = list() 
tab2 = list() 
j = 0

for output in y:
    if output == 0 :
        tab0.append(j)
    if output == 1 :
        tab1.append(j)
    if output == 2 :
        tab2.append(j)
    j = j + 1

########################################################################
#Computation intra similarity#
import math

sim0_intra = list()
sim1_intra = list()
sim2_intra = list()

#Classes stores 1,2,3 ( the 3classes), count the number of elements in each classes
classes, count = np.unique(y, return_counts=True)

temp = 0

for i in tab0:
    temp = 0
    for j in tab0:
        for k in range(len(X[0])):
            temp = temp + np.square(X[i][k] - X[j][k])

    sim0_intra.append(np.sqrt(temp / ( count[0] - 1)) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances` which returns you a distance matrix, and by default it is using 'euclidean' similarity (the function you computed in your example).

You'll find everything here
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html

And here, some code ;)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.metrics import  pairwise 

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
Y = iris.target

# dividing X by classes {0,1,2} to perform intra-distances
X0 = X[np.where(Y==0)] 
X1 = X[np.where(Y==1)]
X2 = X[np.where(Y==2)]

sim0_intra = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X0, metric='euclidean')
sim1_intra = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X1, metric='euclidean')
sim2_intra = pairwise.pairwise_distances(X2, metric='euclidean')
```

As the documentation states, pairwise_distances returns  "**A distance matrix D such that D_{i, j} is the distance between the ith and jth vectors of the given matrix X**"

So, in our case, for example:
`sim0_intra[0][1] --> 0.53851648071346281` is the distance between first and second elements of class 0. And  no surprise if you ask for something like `sim0_intra[5][5] --> 0.0` and observe that distance is 0,  as you are asking for distance to the element itself which is none :)

And finally, you could ask for the mean value in each matrix and that would give you the intra-similarity:

```
similarityClass0 = sim0_intra.sum()/(50*50-50) # output: 0.69812194319103826
similarityClass1 = sim1_intra.sum()/(50*50-50) # output: 0.99736067331161615
similarityClass2 = sim2_intra.sum()/(50*50-50) # output: 1.1767808010528609
```

I'm calculating myself the mean (there should be prettier ways to do it). I'm adding up all distances (which are by the way added twice) and dividing by the total number of elements (50*50) but substracting the ones that are in the diagonal.

*Note: I've tried several things, as `np.triu` which gives you the upper part of the matrix and then tried to call `mean` but it does the mean by taking into account the lower part of the matrix as well, being now 0. So... if any prettier ways to do it come up, please share! :)*

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Guiem is indeed straightforward. I have just to add this line after you calculated the distance matrix

```
    D_triu = np.triu(D)
    intra_class_dist = np.mean(D_triu[D_triu > 0])
```

since np.triu() creates an upper triangular matrix with elements below the k-th diagonal zeroed

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.triu.html

hence, you need to discard them from the calculation of the mean.